# Typo3 News Plugin

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x

I am beginner to Typo3. I am using Typo3 Version 8.7.10 with site package.
I want to know how to override the styles of plugins ( News..).

I used the following news plugin:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/

I added news plugin reference in Setup.typoscript and constants.txt file

templateRootPaths {0 = EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/}

Even checked in Templates-Typoscript Object Browser. All my template references are correct but in the front-end news plugin styles are not overridden.

Any ideas? what may be the problem here?[constants.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ainMi.png)
[setup.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuZmS.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation? There is a good How-To to change and edit templates: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html

Comment: Ya. I read the document and copied the news directory from Resources/Private/ 
 and pasted in my project folder "D:\..\..\..\..\htdocs\typo3conf\ext\my_sitepackage\Resources\Private\Templates\News" and changed the path in Setup.typoscript (1 = EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/News/) and in constants.txt (templateRootPath = EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/News/) but still if i change something in EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/News it is not reflecting in the Front-End. What may be the issue. do i need to do something else? Thanks in advance..

Comment: The ordering is wrong. Your sitepackage paths should be loaded after the ones from news. In your setup.txt your order is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the order and its working fine. I have one small doubt.
i changed the following files
1.D:\..\..\..\..\htdocs\typo3conf\ext\news\Configuration\TypoScript\constants.txt
2.D:\..\..\..\..\htdocs\typo3conf\ext\news\Configuration\TypoScript\setup.txt
3.D:\..\..\..\..\htdocs\typo3conf\ext\my_sitepackage\Configuration\TypoScript\setup.typoscript
4.D:\..\..\..\..\htdocs\typo3conf\ext\my_sitepackage\Configuration\TypoScript\constants.typoscript
is it correct? or do i need to change the files only in my_sitepackage?Thanks a lot for ur help..

Comment: Please do not change files in third party extensions. These changes will be overwritten on the next update.

Answer (score -1):

EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/News/
is wrong, please use:
EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/ (without the subfolder "News", same for Partials and Layouts (if needed)
EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/
EXT:my_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Layouts/

Comment: Its bcz i created a new folder "News" in my_sitepackage and copied news plugin template files into that.. to make clear view for news plugin. Is it wrong ? Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: This is wrong, you can define any folder, it don't need to end with `Templates`, `Partials` or `Layouts`.